# I am using curl-logger with RestAssured and Java.I want to log curl requests to either text file or log file

Tags: logging, curl, api

I am getting this issue while generating curl commands on windows:

```
--user "ashish:a26B)n^A?"%"6Wf!AsJw,
```

`!AsJw` is creating problem. I'm adding the full request below:

```
curl "https://api2-preprod.incentivenetworks.com/v0/auth/wl?partner_id=81211&iv=ExtLVWGlIkfSC32qOf5DUw"%"253D"%"253D"%"250A&token=9ydAWTxZ7qb9hXqKBELZ8MU0pN8IsSF53Bgu0tGe4BeYIpqWp"%"25252FYr6L5wDidRqWWTvvWFS9DPXtqd"%"25250A5a8cc9vOovxnUGyCykVERBoEQd7LtuIVKIPNNeCDdfHsGhRgj"%"25252B4ol8B9XiKB"%"25252F5gc8eXy3Z"%"25252BUq1ka"%"25250AmTzKmCwR9WGXgKkTAw1rJbgxPThgkhmSwK4g08lt"%"25252B4j5FUt2sI1r9cizNfyJnw"%"25253D"%"25253D"%"25250A" --cookie "LSE5Xgebmy-_8Po7xHRyAlTVqKVtHI8D9lkYWu8VkUrY1gkOqMt1WG9XfMB1pRwpxb-AR5W2ApPl4y6aVa4TrrnWdLQLWhe7PybJuIZHmPipzh96kBrkMfH-gZ17hKChY8mfQbUtkND6EOMjiiGMhQ8Im3OuKbKDa6tM7gKCzHA=null" --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" --header "Accept: */*" --header "Host: api2-preprod.incentivenetworks.com" --header "Connection: Keep-Alive" --header "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/11.0.1)" --user "ashish:a26B)n^A?"%"6Wf!AsJw" --compressed --insecure --verbose
```

This is what is getting printed. But if I remove `!AsJw` Then request works well. This value is System generated.

Comment: Not a solution, but I usually build my complicated curl / wget requests with cliget in firefox. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/   I wonder if this issue has to do with non-escapable characters in windows CLI?   Have you tried another interpreter like git-bash or even python?

Comment: I am using curl-logger plugin with windows to generate curl requests on console and what i posted above is getting generated.OfCourse,If i give correct curl request by removing those special characters,it works even on git-bash.

Comment: My Question is while generating curl request where this user value comes from in the request.Is it set by developers or devops Guys sothat i can get those characters removed from the value.

Comment: I'm the author of curl-logger (https://github.com/dzieciou/curl-logger). Can you provide the original request? Which version of curl-logger are you using?